# get bash history to vi

Tags: bash, vim

When I try to read bash history into vim, I get nothing.

```
:r !history
```

If I just execute the command, i.e.

```
:!history
```

instead of history I get a snapshot of my terminal as it looked before I started vim.

How can I read the output of "history" into vim? Reading the contents of .bash_history won't do as I save history with timestamps:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%Y.%m.%d %R  '
```

Comment: Hm, history seems to have some special semantics.  While trying to come up with an answer I noticed `bash -c history` does not output anything.  Odd...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From a shell prompt:

```
history | vim -
```

Comment: Brilliant! A textbook example of thinking outside the box. Plus this is the only solution that includes the unsaved history from the current shell.

Comment: @nameanyone, how can it be textbook and outside the box at the same time? ;)

Comment: @hasenj Thinking Outside the Box for Dummies?

Comment: Exactly the idea I was looking for. Taking it one step further, this will also get you to the last line of the history, so the result is identical to running `history`, with the difference that you are in vim interface: `history | vim "+normal G$" -`

Answer (score 20):

The problem is that that history is only known by the bash shell that started vim.  When you do `:!history` from within vim, you're starting a new bash shell that has its own history, which is empty, which is why you just see the screen as it looked when you started vim: it's outputting all the lines in its history, which is a grand total of zero.  This actually is an oversimplification, but anyway you can't get a history of the commands that you typed just before starting vim this way.

If you want to get those lines of history without exiting vim, you can suspend vim by pressing `CTRL-Z` and then write the history to a file using `history >history.tmp`.  Then type `fg 1` to resume vim: this will tell bash to transfer focus back to its "job number 1", which will normally be vim.  The job number is displayed after you hit CTRL-Z:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vim
```

so if there's a number other than 1 in the brackets, then you should do `fg` for that number instead.  Then (hopefully you know this) when you're back in vim just `:tabedit history.tmp`, for example, to open the saved history in a new tab.

You'll have timestamps in this output too, but since you're in vim you can easily filter them out with a `:substitute` command.  Alternatively you can cut them out using `HISTTIMESTAMP='' history` rather than just `history` when writing to the file; this will still output the index of each entry.  I guess you can filter that out on its way into the file too, by piping it through `sed` or `cut` or one of their crew.  But it's really easy to do this from within vim (assuming you know the basics of regular expressions; if not, start with `:help :substitute` or maybe look for a regex tutorial).

Note that if you read in the lines from ~/.bash_history, you're only getting the history from bash shells which have **completed**, ie you typed `exit` and the terminal window closed.  So any commands you typed just before starting vim won't be there.  You can change the way this works but then you end up with commands from different sessions all jumbled up together in the history.

Answer (score 13):

```
:r!echo "history" | bash -i 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/\x1b\[.//g'
```

---

### Explanation:

The history command only works on interactive shell.

**The first part:**

```
echo "history" | bash -i 2>/dev/null
```

Forces interactive shell (and removes lines which aren't output of history).

**The second part:**

```
sed -e 's/\x1b\[.//g'
```

Removes escape character the shell might output (happened on my system).

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Neat trick that I am sure can come useful in many situations. If I could accept two answers I would.

Comment: The best answer ! :r!echo "history" | bash -i 2>/dev/null | cut -c 8- | tail -n 4

Answer (score 4):

You may pre-write the history of current session:
`history -w`
Then in editor you can get last, say, 20 commands of history:
`:r ! tail -20 ~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
r !set -o history; HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; history -r; history 10
```

This will include the timestamps and will not include history that hasn't been saved to the history file.