# Access Bash CLI history from within VIM

Tags: bash, vim, command-line-interface

In VIM one can run a Bash command with `:!<command>`. How can one access the Bash history in this fashion in order to rerun previous commands (that were run on the CLI, not in VIM), just as one would press the Up arrow at the CLI?

Comment: Have you looked at [conqueTerm](http://code.google.com/p/conque/)?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512336/get-bash-history-to-vi)

Comment: @SpencerRathbun: That doesn't help to rerun a Bash command from within VIM, but it is a nice plugin that should come in handy for other uses. Thanks!

Comment: @JaypalSingh: It doesn't help to have the whole history open in a buffer, I still cannot rerun a command. However, there are some interesting information in that post and it will do me good to read it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just

1. `<C-z>`
2. use bash like I normally do
3. `fg`

Edit: I actually use [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) so I don't do the above method as much as I used to use it. Now I do this:

1. `<C-a>`
2. use bash
3. `<C-aa>`
4. use vim
5. `<C-aa>`
6. use bash
   ... repeat as needed

Comment: So... simple! Thanks, Ctrl-Z really is the right solution. However I know that I must start to learn screen!